Azure Data Factor dataflow filter array objects
I'm new to ADF. I have thousands of JSON files where I want to find value in the "hobbies" array, such as "tennis" or "reading." I'm unsure if using the derived column setting is the correct way to do it before sending it to the filter activity. Return the entire json file to sink If the values match.
example json
{
 
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Laura Smith",
  "hobbies": ["tennis", "painting", "yoga"]
}

derivedColumn1 in the dataflow setting.
hobbies_reading column:   contains(hobbies, 'reading')
hobbies_tennis column:   contains(hobbies, 'tennis')
hobbies_match column:    (hobbies_reading || hobbies_tennis)
Filter1 setting:
!isNull(hobbies_match)


Can you provide your expected output?

the output is the entire JSON file if matches reading or tennis in an array.


You are getting the above error because you are using columns from the same derived column transformation. The above columns cannot be used in the same transformation, these can only be used after this transformation. You can have another derived column transformation after this to create the hobbies_match column.
Instead, you can achieve your requirement with a single filter transformation using the below expression.
contains(hobbies,#item=='reading') || contains(hobbies,#item=='tennis')


This will give the desired rows from the source JSON files.

You can have derived column transformation for the filename column either before or after the filter transformation which won't affect the output of the filter transformation.
Add your sink withe the required configurations and run the pipeline. It will generate the required JSON files as shown below.

